# How to read a text file from url in android

Tags: android, url

I wanna to write an app that need to recive some text from server 
this is my code :

```
String db = ""
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Create a URL for the desired page
                    URL url = new URL("http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt");

                    // Read all the text returned by the server
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
                        db+=str;
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

            }
        }).start();

        searchEditText.setText(dbd);
```

it seems right but the variable db is stil "" in the end .

Comment: "But it doesn't work".  Seriously?  400+ rep and the error we get is " it doesn't work "?

Comment: There is no runtime or compile error ! its a logical error ! the variable db is empty in the end ! and I dont know how to fix it

Comment: what is this "dbdbd" variable? Did you add internet permission?

Comment: Well if `db` is empty it likely means your while loop is never executed, which means that there's likely no content to be read from the stream.  Start there.

Comment: is it *really* empty? You run an operation in background but try to set the text immediately after the Thread is started

Comment: You should place `Log` calls in your `catch` statements so you know whether any errors are occuring.

Comment: Or at least print a stack trace...

Comment: seems like you do not understand basics of multithreading ... http://ideone.com/PPHi95 ... as you can see output is 1-3-2 not 1-2-3 ... you have the same situation

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

Hope that will solve your problem.

Note : Firstly you must do networking operation in another thread because networking in main thread makes your application unresponsive for duration of any request. So put this code in [AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).

```
DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

        BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

        InputStream is = buf.getContent();


        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String data;
        while ((data= r.readLine()) != null) {
            text .append(line + "\n");
        }

        searchEditText.setText(text );
```

Comment: the data would be null :|

Comment: Try some other file and test. You will get to know what is the exact problem.